# What is the best way to check if 4 integer variables are equal to 0?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have 4 non negative integer values a,b,c and d.how i can check if a,b,c and d all are equal to 0 in best way?
Which is the best practice for minimum computation

> if(a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)

or

> if(a+b+c+d==0)

or any other best way in java?

Comment: `if(a)` is automatically `false` when `a=0`, at least in C, C++ and many other languages, it would be helpful to know which language you are adopting.

Comment: perform binary or for all the variables and check for zero

Comment: You mean non-negative values, right?

Comment: @user2485710 In most languages.

Comment: The answer may depend on the language of programming in, which you have neglected to mention!

Comment: The answer to this question is going to be language-dependent. Voting to close until you add a specification of a language.

Answer (score 7):

```
if((a|b|c|d) == 0)
```

with bitwise or

Comment: `(a|b|c|d)==0` has another advantage over `(a+b+c+d==0)`: You don't need to worry about arithmetic overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is

```
if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)
```

This stops the comparison as soon as one variable is not zero, and performs one comparison for each variable if all variables are zero.

It also expresses clearly what you're trying to do, namely checking if all variables are zero. Twiddling bits might bring a small advantage (or not – measure it!), but it obfuscates your code and clearly falls into the field of micro optimization.

Comment: But jumps are expensive.

Comment: If you have profiled your program and determined that a jump is more expensive than bit twiddling, then sure, go for the bit twiddling. But I'd be surprised if this brings a major speed improvement compared to the optimizations to other parts of the code that you could do in the same time. And keep in mind that obfuscated code is expensive, too.

Comment: Also note that both `if((a|b|c|d) == 0)` and `if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)` perform exactly the same number of jumps. (One jump to the `else` branch if one of the variables is not zero.)

Answer (score 1):

You could check that the largest of the numbers is zero, or check whether their sum (arithmetic or [logical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)) is zero.

There is no single universal "best" way.

If you are aiming for clarity, it's hard to beat `if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0 && d==0)`.

If you are aiming for performance, you'll need to:

1. establish that performance of this piece of code actually matters;
2. benchmark the various approaches using your compiler, target hardware and typical inputs.

Comment: Mathematically, you can take the sum, but you have no way in Java to statically ensure that your numbers are indeed non-negative, hence `(a|b|c|d) == 0` would be safer *and* works for any integers.

Comment: When using the sum approach, you'd also have to deal with the possibility of integer overflow.

Comment: Yes, the following fails: a=b=c=d=0x40000000. yields 0

Answer (score 1):

perform binary Or operation on all the variables and check its Binary or is Zero

`(a | b | c | d) == 0`

Comment: +1, best answer, this also works when negative numbers are among them.